# Always need to clear cache

Tags: javascript, facebook, caching, localhost

I have a facebook app I am testing on my `localhost`. It's quite annoying that I always need to clear the cache in order to reload after making changes. Any idea how can I solve this?

I've heard from some friends that some Javascript code might be helpful, but I have no idea what to actually do.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If u are posting data to your app provide an extra variable which contains the current time. Then your requests will always be treated as new ones

Comment: For now, I am only getting data in my code

Comment: Read this http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/

Comment: @ParthikGosar thing is that I would really need something that is for my entire app. I have for example `iframe`s that load `php`s and they would, I guess also need something like that. And I quite have a lot of files

Answer (score 1):

have you tried the google chrome developer tools? they have an option to disable all cache when they are open.

I normally open the dev tools (mac: command+alt+i), with disabled cache (click on the settings button on the bottom right) and then hold down shift and click reload to make sure all cache is erased.

[image: dev tools settings]

Comment: Thanks for the tip- but the question will be in that case if I won't have the same problem when I will put everything on the server and launch my app

Comment: i once had the problem where i had to reload a gif and by putting a timestamp on it, so it restarts the animation, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839634/replay-a-gif-animation-reload-gif-on-click

Comment: My question is if the user won't have the same problem. I now have it on my localhost and it is all fine, but when I will launch the app, I won't just tell the user "disable the cache before using my app", but I wouldn't either tell my user to clear the cache whenever he uses the app.

Comment: got it, thought you needed it for developing...location.reload(true) refreshes the page with no cache i believe...

Comment: As I said, thanks for the developing tip. It is indeed partially what i needed, but I still need something that will work when it will be accessed by the users.
The problem is still that is the user will refresh the window, instead of myself doing `location.reload(true)`, it will still crash

Comment: so you would need to force a cache free reload in your onload function? and when the user hits the back key?

Comment: Basically, I think I would like to disable caching

Comment: ur not afraid that will slow down your app? there is this option similar to reloading a gif animation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942242/disable-browser-cache